# How to populate or update column value in an excel sheet based on data values in another reference column

Tags: excel

I have two excel sheets: One have basic set of data as shown below. It have only three rows of data.

[image]

Now, my second sheet have 7 rows of data as shown below, but first column is empty.

[image]

Now, I want to update the first column of my second sheet using reference data of first sheet as shown below. I searched and used concatenation function but it is not working.

To make it simple, we can assume that both of the data sets are available on single sheet but under different columns. Wondering how to update the first column value?
[image]

Edit: Complete set of data with column name:
[image]

Comment: This is a simple `=VLOOKUP()` formula.  But you didn't show the sheet names or the column/row names, so it's hard to give a better suggestion or answer.

Comment: Thanks: I added another sheet. Column 'C' and 'D' have reference data. And i want column 'E' needs to be updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first sheet is `Sheet1` and your second sheet is `Sheet2`, and all of our data is in columns A and B on the two sheets, then you can use a formula like this in `Sheet2` (adjust `B1` to match the row you enter the formula into):

```
=VLOOKUP(B1,Sheet1!A:B,2,FALSE)
          | \--------/ |   \------- find an exact match
          |      |     \----------- return the value from the 2nd column of the array
          |      \----------------- find the value in the first column of this array
          \------------------------ value to find
```

This takes the value `aajain` in cell `B1` on `Sheet2` and find the value in the first column (`A`) on `Sheet1`, and returns the second column (`2`) value.  Using `False` in the formula tells it to use an exact match instead of an approximate match.